# View composer not working properly in testing mode in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, functional-testing

I've a view composer written like this

```
view()->composer('masterbox.partials.pipeline', function($view) {
  // Some vars and code
});
```

In one of my view I do as follow

```
@include('masterbox.partials.pipeline', ['my_var' => 1])
```

When i'm trying it on my browser everything is fine, but when I run a simple test everything blows up ... After some debugging I found out the closure wasn't executed at all.

```
$this->visit('/connect/customer/subscribe')
      ->type($faker->firstName, 'first_name')
      ->type($faker->firstName, 'first_name')
      ->type($faker->lastName, 'last_name')
      ->type($faker->email, 'email')
      ->type($faker->phoneNumber, 'phone')
      ->type($password, 'password')
      ->type($password, 'password_confirmation')
      ->press("S'inscrire");
```

**Note : It visits a page, fills the form and subscribe, then it redirects on the page with the `@include` and it returns a big error, part of it is**

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: my_var' in /Users/Loschcode/Google Drive/projects/my_project_lo/website/storage/framework/views/7e11f284c02bc38adc60b5f8a0545df65d7cf5ec.php:7
```

I'm afraid it an issue, it's a fresh Laravel 5.2 I downloaded a few days ago. Any guess ? Any method to debug this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Working solution

I ended up trying anything. My problem was my service provider organization.

```
    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Bootstrap the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {

          foreach (glob(app_path().'/Http/ViewComposers/*.php') as $filename){  
            require_once($filename);
          }

        }

        /**
         * Register the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

If you have a similar organization and problem, replace the `require_once` by a simple `require` and everything will go fine.

```
    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Bootstrap the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {

          foreach (glob(app_path().'/Http/ViewComposers/*.php') as $filename){  
            require($filename);
          }

        }

        /**
         * Register the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```